# How to format automatically top output for logging?

Tags: linux, top

Currently my top command output is shown as:

```
14861 root      20   0  0.252t 0.028t    556 S  13.3 92.8   8:45.64
```

I want the display of this in m. It is presently showing in t. I am getting the above output with the below command:

```
top -b -p 14861 -n1 |tail -1
```

Is there any option to achieve the same. I will be writing this top output to a log using for loop. So I will not be able to do anything manually.

I even tried with small letter e, that doesn't convert for some of the processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command like this:

```
top -b -p 14861 -n1 |tail -1|awk '{$5=$5*1024*1024; $6=$6*1024*1024} 1'
```

Comment: thanks but need to manipulate the output itself right, no direct option available in top command itself?

Comment: @Programmer, not sure it is possible in batch mode. Can be modified only in visual mode